# Using utf8proc in thread safe and reentrant code

Tags: c, unicode, thread-safety, posix, reentrancy

I am refactoring a legacy C application to make it Unicode aware. It currently uses `char*` for strings. I have come across the [utf8 library](http://www.flexiguided.de/publications.utf8proc.en.html), but the documentation is sparse and I can't work out whether it is suitable to be used in code that is expected to be threadsafe and re-entrant.

Does anyone know the definite answer as to whether utf8proc can be used in a threadsafe (POSIX), re-entrant code environment?

Comment: Note that you can use `char *` for UTF-8 strings just fine, the only issue is that the length of a string in bytes might not be the same as the length of a string in UTF-8 characters.  If you use a UTF-8 based locale, you can use `strcoll` and `strxfrm` to handle pretty much everything not handled by stuff that's not particulary UTF-8 aware.

Comment: Well, length in bytes is probably more important than in "characters", which is itself an ambiguous term. More here: http://utf8everywhere.org/#myth.strlen

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source code, it seems pretty clear that the utf8proc library is re-entrant and thread-safe (assuming you have thread-safe malloc/realloc/free).  It doesn't use any non-const global variables, has no static local variables, calls few standard library functions other than memory allocation, and in general is just straightforward iteration over heap-allocated buffers.